# Remove double quotes from line

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this

> "He said, ""What?"""

In the entire file, there's actually more lines like that, separated by commas. The output of that line should look something like this:

> He said, "What?!!"

I'm trying to do that by using this method:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*)\\s*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while (matcher.find()) 
            {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                lines.add(matcher.group(1)); //adds each line to an arraylist
            }
```

However, the output I'm getting is this:

```
He said,
What?
```

I'm pretty sure the cause is with my regular expressions since all this does is remove all the double quotes.

Comment: Is `lines` is supposed to represent individual lines? If so then when you call `group()` it will have a separate results per line.

Comment: What are your expected values from this match?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use String#replaceAll

```
line.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: I still need to separate each line into smaller segments and store those segments into an arraylist.

Comment: That will remove all double quotes from input.

Comment: Oh, so you want the outside double quotes still intact?, I may not be understanding your desired output.

Comment: That's still just an alias for `matcher.replaceAll()`, only without caching the Pattern. Retaining quotes could mean using lookbehind or replacing with a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your regular expression matches

```
"He said, "
```

then

```
"What?"
```

then

```
""
```

It seems like what you actually want is to remove *one level* of double-quotes. To do that, you need to use lookaround assertions:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\"(?!\")[^\"]*(?<!\")\"\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

The process of forming quoted string is:

1. Escape (double) the double quotes in the string
2. Surround the resulting string with double quotes

The code below just reverses this process:

It first removes the outer double quotes, then un-escapes the inner double quotes, and then splits:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "\"He said, \"\"What?\"\"\"";
    String[] out = input.replaceAll("^(\")|(\")$", "").replace("\"\"", "\"").split(", ");
    for (String o : out) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
He said
"What?"
```